# Tag operations for tagged transitions in TDFA(tagged DFA) for sub regex matching

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner at Haskell programming. I was trying to match strings for regex using Haskell programming + TDFA for regex backend. And, I did successfully sub-regex matching operations, but not using tags concept proposed in TDFA. For example please see the following code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}

import Control.Monad
import Data.Array
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Text.Regex.TDFA
import Text.Regex.TDFA.Common       

str = "bbbb" :: String
regex = "(b|bb|bbb|bbbb)*" :: String
```

/*   regex = "(tag1 b|tag2 bb|tag3 bbb|tag4 bbbb)*" :: String ---->interested now */

```
main = do
  if str =~ regex then putStrLn "matched" else putStrLn "no matches"

  let matches = getAllTextMatches (str =~ regex) :: Array Int (Array Int String)
  print matches
-- Output: array (0,1) [(0,array (0,1) [(0,"bbbb"),(1,"bbbb")]),(1,array (0,1) [(0,""),(1,"")])]

  let matches = getAllTextMatches $ str =~ regex :: [Array Int String]
  print matches
-- Output: [array (0,1) [(0,"bbbb"),(1,"bbbb")],array (0,1) [(0,""),(1,"")]]

  let matches = getAllTextMatches $ str =~ regex :: Array Int [String]
  print matches
-- Output: array (0,1) [(0,["bbbb","bbbb"]),(1,["",""])]

  let matches = getAllTextMatches $ str =~ regex :: Array Int String
  print matches
-- Output: array (0,1) [(0,"bbbb"),(1,"")]

  let matches = getAllTextMatches $ str =~ regex :: [String]
  print matches
-- Output: ["bbbb",""]

  let matches = str =~ regex :: [[String]]
  print matches
-- Output: [["bbbb","bbbb"],["",""]]

  let matches = getAllTextMatches $ str =~ regex :: Array Int (MatchText String)
  print matches
-- Output: array (0,1) [(0,array (0,1) [(0,("bbbb",(0,4))),(1,("bbbb",(0,4)))]),(1,array (0,1) [(0,("",(4,0))),(1,("",(-1,0)))])]

-- Using getAllMatches

  let matches = getAllMatches $ str =~ regex :: Array Int MatchArray
  print matches
-- Output: array (0,1) [(0,array (0,1) [(0,(0,4)),(1,(0,4))]),(1,array (0,1) [(0,(4,0)),(1,(-1,0))])]

  let matches = getAllMatches $ str =~ regex :: Array Int (MatchOffset,MatchLength)
  print matches
-- Output: array (0,1) [(0,(0,4)),(1,(4,0))]

  let matches = getAllMatches $ str =~ regex :: [(MatchOffset,MatchLength)]
  print matches
-- Output: [(0,4),(4,0)]
```

Anyways, now, I am actually very much interested to see how tags operations on TDFA are performing while matching the subexpression for the accepted input strings. For example,

Let's we have a regex, `R = (b|bb|bbb|bbbb)*` and input string = `"bbbb"`. So, using TDFA concept if I rewrite the regex `R = (tag1 b| tag2 bb | tag3 bbb| tag4 bbbb)*` and then if I try to match it for the input string = `"bbbb"` then, my interest is to see how many times `these tags{1,2,3,4}` are performing to match the regex `R`. As, on the given input string `"bbbb"`, first `b` will be the extent of matched `tag1`, same as input substring `"bb"` of `"bbbb"` will be the extent of `tag2`, and so on. This is how, if we now consider the full given input string `"bbbb"` then `tag4` will give the extent of it also at the same time will give the result such that `"bbb"` of `"bbbb"` matched the extent of `tag3`, same as `"bb"` of `"bbbb"` matched the extent of `tag2` and, finally `"b"` of `"bbbb"` matched the extent of `tag1`. Thus, I want to see these operations `using the TDFA module`. That's it. I mean, `how many times these tags have to be updated in order to match the sub-regex withing the regex for the given accepted input string`. That's it.

Thus, any kind of help would be a lot to me...:) 
P.S.: It's a challenge for the Haskell beginner, thus looking for Haskell hacker. I mean sagacious one...:) Anyways,, hope for the best...:)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to write explicit tags into the regexp passed to Regex-TDFA. Regex-TDFA supports [POSIX regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/re.html), and in POSIX submatch extraction concerns *capturing groups* (that is, parenthesized subexpressions). You can use capturing groups with Regex-TDFA as follows:

```
Prelude Text.Regex.TDFA> "bbbb" =~ "((b)|(bb)|(bbb)|(bbbb))*" :: MatchArray
array (0,5) [(0,(0,4)),(1,(0,4)),(2,(-1,0)),(3,(-1,0)),(4,(-1,0)),(5,(0,4))]
```

Here you see that your expression has 6 capturing groups: `(b)`, `(bb)`, `(bbb)`, `(bbbb)`, `((b)|(bb)|(bbb)|(bbbb))` and the whole regexp, which in POSIX is always the implicit first group.

1. the whole regexp matches at offset `0` and spans `4` symbols
2. `((b)|(bb)|(bbb)|(bbbb))` matches at offset `0` and spans `4` symbols
3. `(b)` does not match -- hence the starting offset `-1` and match length `0`
4. likewise `(bb)` does not match
5. likewise `(bbb)` does not match
6. finally, `(bbbb)` matches at offset `0` and spans `4` symbols.

You can use submatch extraction with other interfaces as well:

```
Prelude Text.Regex.TDFA> "bbbb" =~ "((b)|(bb)|(bbb)|(bbbb))*" :: [[String]]
[["bbbb","bbbb","","","","bbbb"],["","","","","",""]]
```

The *tags* are added implicitly by Regex-TDFA internal algorithm -- they are an implementation detail hidden from the user. If what you want is submatch extraction with Haskell regexp, then you should stop reading at this point. If, however, you are interested in Regex-TDFA theory of operation, than the answer to your question is much more involved.

Regex-TDFA is based on the concept of Tagged DFA, [invented by Ville Laurikari](https://laurikari.net/ville/spire2000-tnfa.pdf) in 2000.

Chris Kuklewicz, the author of Regex-TDFA, extended Ville's algorithm to support POSIX disambiguation semantics. He informally described his disambiguation algorithm [on Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/index.php?title=Regular_expressions/Bounded_space_proposal&oldid=11475) in 2007, and [recently showed little interest](https://github.com/ChrisKuklewicz/regex-tdfa/issues/12) in its formalization or development.

Kuklewicz disambiguation algorithm was adopted in [lexer generator RE2C](http://re2c.org) and formalized in [this unpublished paper](http://re2c.org/2017_trofimovich_tagged_deterministic_finite_automata_with_lookahead.pdf) (of which I happen to be the author). RE2C also supports leftmost greedy disambiguation semantics and allows you to [use explicit tags](http://re2c.org/manual/features/submatch/submatch.html). See also the simple example of [parsing IPv4 address](http://re2c.org/examples/example_08.html) or the more complex [URI RFC-3986 parsing](http://re2c.org/examples/example_10.html) example to get the idea.

Back to your question:

> how many times these tags have to be updated in order to match the sub-regex withing the regex for the given accepted input string

The answer is, it depends on the *non-determinism degree* of the given regular expression (see [the paper](http://re2c.org/2017_trofimovich_tagged_deterministic_finite_automata_with_lookahead.pdf), page 16, for the explanation). For a simple *tag-deterministic* regexp it is an insignificant constant-time overhead. For pathological cases with bounded repetition, see example 5 in the paper (page 21). See also the benchmarks (pages 27-29), they show that in real-world tests the overhead on submatch extraction is quite modest.

Note also that Regex-TDFA uses *lazy* derminization, that is, all the overhead on determinization and POSIX disambiguation is in run-time, therefore the overall overhead on submatch extraction is greater than in RE2C case.

Finally, you can explore Regex-TDFA internals by using `examineDFA` debug function defined in `/Text/Regex/TDFA/TDFA.hs` and further tweaking it to print the information you need.

Comment: `@skvadrik` Thank you so much ma'am for your nice feedback. However, in the meantime I have found something more interesting. Anyways, your response means a lot to me, ok. Once again, thank you....:)